# How to take my email id from login class of another view class for further manipulation?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This my login class

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button registerHere;
    Button signIn;
    TextInputLayout emailLogin;
    TextInputLayout passwordLogin;
    EditText etEmailLogin;
    EditText etPasswordLogin;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
         getSupportActionBar().hide();
        //initializing toolbar //        Toolbar toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        //initializing views
        registerHere=(Button)findViewById(R.id.registerhere_button);
        signIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin_button);
        emailLogin=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.email_loginlayout);
        passwordLogin=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.password_loginlayout);
        etEmailLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_login);
        etPasswordLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_login);
        //setting onclick listeners
        registerHere.setOnClickListener(this);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        //setting progressDialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());


        //If the session is logged in move to MainActivity
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }


    /**
     * function to verify login details
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);



                    Boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

//                    System.out.println("Your now at if" + error);


                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

//                        Details details=new Details(); //         
details.setUser_email(jObj.getString("email")); //                  
details.setUser_name(jObj.getString("name"));
                        // Launching  main activity
                        String username=jObj.getString("name");
                        String email=jObj.getString("email");

                        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putString("email", email);
                        editor.putString("name",username);
                        editor.apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class); //                        String email=details.getUser_email(); //                       
String name=details.getUser_name(); //                       
intent.putExtra("email", email); //                       
intent.putExtra("name", name); //                       
System.out.println("msg"+email); //                       
System.out.println("msg"+name);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else {
                        // login error
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Post params to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "login");
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to  queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Here now am trying store the email from the user using sharedpreference.

My main acvity class is contain onit method only,i tried to get the email in this class as follows

```
     public class MainActivity extends NavigationActionBarLiveo 
    implements OnItemClickListener {
    //naviagtion Drawer libarary

    private HelpLiveo mHelpLiveo;
    private static final String TAG =MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private SessionManager session;


    SharedPreferences pref;

   // SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public void onInt(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String p= pref.getString("email", null);
        System.out.println(p+"print");
```

}

but i try to run the app i got error as :Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing session data, save it within the application using Shared Preferences. If the user logs out put these values as null.

Put this in your Manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Example :

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

//to save data
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("key_email", email);
editor.apply();

//to load data
String email = preferences.getString("key_email", null);
```

Comment: Ok then how can i acess the it from my viewactvity class?

Comment: I did it but at that time its crashed

Comment: Now i update the code and try get the email id ifrom log in actvitiy but the app crashes and showing the errors as Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you initialise preferences object and you need to first put a string with that key value before accessing it.

Comment: nope ,now am adding the permission and will cacth you after that

Comment: soory its again crashed ,error as Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Hi now i updated my code ,can you pls look at the edited code above

Comment: You need to add                         SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use putExtra(String name, Charsequence value) method available in the Intent class. In the receiving class, u can use the getStringExtra(String key) method on the received intent. Intent in the receiving Activity can be got by getIntent(). Hope this helps!

Comment: public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("email", emailvalue); //put the string value here
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String email = intent.getStringExta("email");
    }
}